# Web Sockets client throwing an exception once it starts receiving data

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I am trying to establish a Web-Socket connection to a server and enter into receive mode.Once the client starts receiving the data, it  immediately  closes the connection with below exception

```
    webSoc_Received = await websocket.recv()
  File "/root/envname/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websockets/protocol.py", line 319, in recv
    raise ConnectionClosed(self.close_code, self.close_reason)
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1007, no reason.
```

Client-side Code Snippet :

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def connect_ws():

    print("websockets.client module defines a simple WebSocket client API::::::")        
    async with websockets.client.connect(full_url,extra_headers=headers_conn1) as websocket:

        print ("starting")
        webSoc_Received = await websocket.recv()
        print ("Ending")
        Decode_data = zlib.decompress(webSoc_Received)      
        print(Decode_data)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(connect_ws())
```

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You use `run_until_complete()` which completes once you started process.
 Instead, you should use [`.run_forever()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_forever). It will keep your socket open, until you close it. 
**EDIT**:
You can do something like this:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.call_soon(connect_ws)  # Calls connect_ws once the event loop starts
loop.run_forever()
```

Or:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(connect_ws())
loop.run_forever()
```

Or if previous examples didn't succeed, you can try with following code:

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def periodic():
  while True:
    print("websockets.client module defines a simple WebSocket client API::::::")        
    with websockets.client.connect(full_url,extra_headers=headers_conn1) as websocket:
       print ("starting")
       webSoc_Received = websocket.recv()
       print ("Ending")
       Decode_data = zlib.decompress(webSoc_Received)      
       print(Decode_data)

def stop():
  task.cancel()

task = asyncio.Task(periodic())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.call_later(5, stop)

try:
   loop.run_until_complete(task)
except asyncio.CancelledError:
   pass
```

Comment: Thanks but its throwing error as I have to call function inside this as well               asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever(connect_ws())
TypeError: run_forever() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.Any idea on this part ?

Comment: With the first method, it just gets stuck and never receives data and stuck at below /usr/local/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py:127: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'connect_ws' was never awaited
  self._callback(*self._args).With second one its same behavior it actually never runs forever

Comment: With your third suggestion its throwing the same error   raise ConnectionClosed(self.close_code, self.close_reason)
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1007, no reason.

Comment: With the second example its same :(

Comment: @CoolNetworking, my bad. I've wrote code for server side. Can you please provide your server side code for websockets. I think it should be something like this http://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#basic-example

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any control over the server-side code, the only thing I know is server will send the data in compressed deflate format so I need to decompress it on the client side and take an action accordingly and server-side code is written in c++ .Can you tell me what needs to be checked on server side code?

Comment: @CoolNetworking, first of all, try to ping server and see does it really send you some messages. As for me, it looks like you try to connect to websocket server and you get no response. If you read documentation about websocket errors, error #1007 - The endpoint is terminating the connection because a message was received that contained inconsistent data (e.g., non-UTF-8 data within a text message). So probably you need to receive binary data. Try to implement code from here https://pymotw.com/2/socket/binary.html

Comment: Actually the only diff is the server is sending a compressed data in deflating algo.So i need to just decompress it on the client side.Anything special needs to be done when it comes to compressed data.How can send ping over websocket,is it just .send and pass ping command ?  @Grynets

Comment: :Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I mean ping, not `ping`, but like echo, to debug and see that server keep sending some data on socket to client. You can do it in any way. 
Try to debug socket data. Maybe you try to connect to protected server without permission, so it bocks your client script.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, your current code will exit after it receives its first message.

Try changing your code to a consumer pattern, as mentioned in the websocket docs here:

https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#common-patterns

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def connect_ws():
        print("websockets.client module defines a simple WebSocket client API::::::")    
        async with websockets.client.connect(full_url,extra_headers=headers_conn1) as websocket:
                while True:
                        print ("starting")
                        webSoc_Received = await websocket.recv()
                        print ("Ending")
                        Decode_data = zlib.decompress(webSoc_Received)      
                        print(Decode_data)
```